# iOS app crashing on iPad when fetching data for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, crash

I have an iOS app targeting iOS 6.0.

I have 3 `UIScrollView`s on a screen, say A, B and C. On the scroll of A I programmatically scroll B and C. It's kind of a grid view.

I need to incorporate infinite scrolling in scrollView A, and I am fetching the data by making a service call after a certain offset is reached.

When I deployed this on iPad, after the 3rd fetch of data, the app abruptly crashes. On the simulator the app works absolutely fine and I have fetched up to 1000 rows.

Please advise on where I should look for/into.

Comment: It seems that it is a memory issue, as it works fine in simulator.

Comment: Profile your app for [memory leaks using instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial).

Comment: Yes It actually a memory issue try test your application using Instruments and look for the live bytes. It works fine on Simulator because Simulator uses memory of your System.

Comment: just received memory warning on the xcode console. The leaks tool we tried on is not showing any memory leaks.

Comment: Then you are probably allocating too much memory. When you get a memory warning, iOS tells you  to free up as much memory as possible. You should do that. Also, you should make sure that you never allocate a lot of memory at all (if possible < 20 MB at max). Use the allocations tool of Instruments to measure that.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the data from that is filling the tables? If it is CoreData, perhaps decreasing the batch size would help, you may be grabbing more data than you need each time.